# Error iterando un diccionario (InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.)

Tags: c#, diccionarios, iteradores

Estoy recibiendo este error al iterar un diccionario ¿Alguien sabe por qué és?

Este es el mensaje de error completo:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration
> operation may not execute.
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection+Enumerator[TKey,TValue].MoveNext
> () (at <9577ac7a62ef43179789031239ba8798>:0)

Este es mi código:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public class Mechanism
{
    public delegate bool Delegate(); 
    public Dictionary<string, Delegate> func;
    public Dictionary<string, bool> state;
    public string currentState="none";

    public Mechanism()
    {
        func = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
        state = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    }
    public void Add(string option, Delegate func)
    {
        this.func.Add(option, func);
        this.state.Add(option, false);
    }
    public void ResetStates()
    {
        if (state.Count <= 0)
            return;

        foreach (string key in state.Keys)
        {
            state[key] = false; //--> el error es en esta línea
        }
        currentState="none";
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------

public class MyClass
{
    public Mechanism mechanism;

    public MyClass()
    {
        mechanism = new Mechanism();
        mechanism.Add("Function1", Function1);
    }

    public bool Function1()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------

public class MainClass
{
    public MyClass myClass;
    
    public MainClass()
    {
        myClass = new MyClass();
    }
  
    public bool InfiniteLoop()
    {
        myClass.mechanism.ResetStates();
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
```

El código se está ejecutando dentro de un loop infinito, no sé si eso tendrá algo que ver.
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: En la misma [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8): especifica que con el foreach solo se puede leer la colección pero no se puede escribir en ella. Esto mas bien es un detalle de implementación. Aquí tienes varias [soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793031/initializing-a-dictionary-to-custom-default-values).

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta!! Vaya!! es una lastima que el foreach se de solo lectura!! Podría ser muy útil si no lo fuera!! Saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lo he solucionado de esta forma... creo que el foreach y los loops infinitos son incompatibles.

```
public void ResetStates()
{
    if (state.Count <= 0) return;

    for (int index = 0; index < state.Count; index++)
    {
        var item = state.ElementAt(index);
        state[item.Key] = false;
    }
}
```

Aquí queda por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda